# Mac app to fuzzy search through PDF files library

Tags: osx, pdf, text-search, ebooks

I'm looking for a Mac app that would be able to index hundreds of books in PDF and perform quick full-text [fuzzy search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) through it.

Comment: Can you select the text inside the PDFs with your mouse? If not, OCR will be needed.

Comment: There are some cases where i can't do that, but let's assume all of the pdf files  are well formatted with selectable text

Answer (score 0):

You could use pythons [pdfminer3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k) to extract the text content and the [FuzzyWuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) library for searching it.

If you are regularly needing to search the same set of pdfs, (possibly with an occasional re-index), you could build an index and possibly do the searches with [nltk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk) but that, while producing much quicker results will take a lot more work up front.